# How to call java method based on js variable value in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

How to call java method based on js variable value in jsp?

GVAR is defined as a global variable and idea is to assign values to it when jsp gets loaded and once the value is assigned it will be available throughout the application (as GVAR is globally defined) The problem is whenever the jsp loads, the server side code gets executed, the if block mentioned below does not work at all as it is client side..What is the best way to check for js variable not null and then only call the server side code to populate it.

```
<script>    
if (GVAR==null) {
GVAR = <%=MyClass.getData("GVAR") %> ;
}
</script>
```

We have many variables which are getting populated by the server side code and checking server side condition every time would become performance bottle neck at some point.

Comment: What is "GVAR"? Is it a Java Script variable? If "yes" then it is not possible. <%=MyClass.getData("GVAR") %> is a server side code which will execute irrespective of any client side (Java script) code. I am not sure about your requirement but using AJAX might help in such scenarios.

Comment: yes..it's a javascript variable (var GVAR)

Comment: Yea I know that this is not possible and I am exploring Rhino to achieve the same. Just wanted to know if there is any other technique which can help here..Let me see if I can fit AJAX call here..the only requirement is not to call server side for all variables if they are already populated..

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty confusing, in the question it says that javascript gets is value from server-variables.

Where as in the comments appear that those server-side variables don't exist and has to be called!

Anyways, let me clear the concept. Seems like you're using JSP & Servlets.

`<%=MyClass.getData("GVAR") %>`

Are you sure that it's even executing and the JSP compiles fine ? Do you get any error in the logs?

The main reason to ask the above question is to make sure that there is proper import for MyClass on the JSP and getData() should be public static (atleast it appears so).

If both conditions are satisfied, please first test the function to see if it actually really works.

Comment: Yes,it is a combination of JSP/Servlets.Ofcourse there are imports,have just included the line to give an idea of what is happening and yes the code works as expected. getData() is static method which takes an arg and reads properties file to get the value of the variable for which request is being made. The js variable is thus assigned this value. This JS variables is defined at theme level and we are populating it on a page.But would want to stop populating it again when same page is rendered since the values are already being assigned to it and will not change.Hope this clears confusion.

Comment: In that case you can consider setting it in sesssion and checking if it's not already available in session before computing again. Or there are various techniques, you can have a static variable and a single line of code, to not compute it, if it's already computed.